# Can i read a MifareUltralight C TAG in iOS 17?

Tags: ios, flutter, nfc

I developed an APP that reads a MifareUltralight C TAG as part of a Cashless System. It reads the TAG to get info previously written to it's blocks by other apps. It works perfect in Android equipments but it doesn't work on iOS.

I'm using a package called nfc_manager in flutter. It has a class called MifareUltralight which has a method called from, that accepts an NfcTag and returns the info of the MifareUltralight C TAG. This works on Android but not in iOS. I'm testing on a iOS 17. I researched a lot about this and added all the necessary entitlements in info.plist to run an app that uses NFC. Does anyone know what the problem could be?